# Python read config file regardless of sections

Tags: python, readfile, configparser, findandmodify

I'm a noob in Python

Problem: Find and replace Keys(strings) in files

For this I'm using Python ConfigParser. But I want to read the whole config (.ini) file into dictionary at once regardless of sections.

1. Is it possible?
2. Is it OK to do so?

I don't want to read a single section at a time

```
dict(Config.items('Section'))
```

Don't want to traverse the sections

```
for each_section in conf.sections():
    for (each_key, each_val) in conf.items(each_section):
        print each_key
        print each_val
```

What other options am I left with?

**-------
Edit 1 
-------**

**Config.ini**

```
[Common]
home_dir: /Users
library_dir: /Library
system_dir: /System
macports_dir: /opt/local

[Frameworks]
Python: 3.2
path: ${Common:system_dir}/Library/Frameworks/

[Arthur]
nickname: Two Sheds
last_name: Jackson
my_dir: ${Common:home_dir}/twosheds
my_pictures: ${my_dir}/Pictures
python_dir: ${Frameworks:path}/Python/Versions/${Frameworks:Python}
```

Below is the file which contains the keys that are to be repalced

```
my dir is home_dir
my lib dir is library_dir
python path is path
My pictures are placed at my_pictures
```

Comment: What is the input? Please add a sample of it? What exatly to you mean by 'tokens'? How are the replacements defined?

Answer (score 0):

If You are looking to have a dictionary that will have all the values in the configuration file as a key value pair irrespective of its **section**, I think you are going in the correct way

```
dict={}
for sec in config.sections():
    for item in config.items(sec):
        dict[item[0]]=item[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are limited to reading through the different sections to get different values for each option in a section.

```
dict_sectionValues = {}
for section in Config.sections():
    for option in Config.options(section):
        value = Config.get(section, option)
        dict_sectionValues[option] = value
```

I think it is a little less readable, but you could reduce to:

```
dict_sectionValues = {}
for section in Config.sections():
    for option in Config.options(section):
        dict_sectionValues[option] = Config.get(section, option)
```